# Visual studio does not show UI while running app

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been working on c# for about 3 hours and Visual Studio does not show the UI while running the application. It shows the UI in designer but after compiling and running, it just goes blank.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us some relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to test:

1. In the code file `Program.cs`, you will find something like this:

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
   ```

   Does the name of the form in the line `Application.Run` match the name of your form?
2. Your form's code behind (Form1.cs) should have a constructor looking like this

   ```
   public Form1() // Where the name of the constructor must match the one of the form class.
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       // Your code goes here (if any) ...
   }
   ```

   Does it have this constructor? If yes, does it call `InitializeComponent`?

`InitializeComponent` is very important, because it creates the controls and configures the form. You may have replaced it with your own code. Always call it before your initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the entry point if your application is wrong. Check the solution properties (right click on your application/solution in the solution explorer -> properties ) for the correct entry point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more than one form.
Go to the Program.cs file and verify if the class of the form is in Application.Run() method

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main ()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles ();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault (false);
            Application.Run (new urltetx());
        }
    }
```